# Make an element ignore event listeners

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is there a way I can make an element, or group of elements, ignore event listeners without changing the event listener code?  The event listener is in a library and I don't want to muck around with the library code.  I want to just put something in my own code that will stop the event listener firing when these particular elements are clicked.

What I am actually trying to do, is stop popups from disappearing when their relative markers are clicked on in a Leaflet map.  I have autoClose and closeOnClick both set to false in the popups.  I have a class for the markers and popups that I can use to access them.

Comment: You need to read about [`stopImmediatePropagation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation)

Comment: `pointer-events: none`. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events .